# getCurrentDirectory() only return the previous directory path

Tags: java, jfilechooser

**Desired output :** 
C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\AFolder\

**Current output** C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\

The code :

```
public String choosePath() throws IOException {
    String fullPath = "";
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    chooser.setDialogTitle("choosertitle");
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = chooser.getCurrentDirectory();
        fullPath = file.getAbsolutePath(); // or getAbsolutePath()
    } else {
        System.out.println("No Selection ");
    }
    return fullPath;
}
```

when I run the code and navigate to C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\AFolder\ the returned string is C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\ , I want it to be C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\AFolder\

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: When you say "navigate to", do you mean that you had the `AFolder` selected, or that you went into the `AFolder`?

Comment: My guess is that the selected file is AFolder. And since its directory is Desktop, that's what is returned by getCurrentDirectory(). Use getSelectedFile().

Comment: @RealSkeptic the Afolder is a folder , so I went into it by double clicking it